# Как сверстать блок за пределами контейнера?

Tags: html, css, css3

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть блок. Внутри него контейнер ограничивающий ширину. Внутри него левый блок с текстом, а рядом картинка, но уже на всю ширину экрана. Как верстается подобное чтоб при адаптиве картинка не налазила на левый блок?

Answer (score 3):

```css
.card {
  display: block;
  max-width: 750px;
  padding: 40px 0 10px 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
}

.card .info {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: flex-start;
  width: 60%;
  min-height: 300px;
  background: #111;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 20px 50px 20px 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.card .info p {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 150%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.card .info::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 3px solid #111;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  left: -10px;
  bottom: -10px;
  z-index: -1;
}

.card .info .bottom {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: flex-start;
  width: 100%;
}

.card .info .bottom .autor span {
  display: block;
}

.card .info .bottom .autor span:nth-child(2) {
  opacity: .45;
}

.card .info .bottom .btn {
  display: inline-flex;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,.25);
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.card .image {
  display: block;
  width: calc(40% + 30px);
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 3;
}

.card .image::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 3px solid #fff;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  left: 5%;
  bottom: 5%;
  z-index: 1;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.card .image img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="info">
    <p>Я создал Trust Macquarie Capital, потому что у меня есть мечта.<br>
    Я хочу, чтобы все наши клиентты имели право на достойную жизнь.</p>
    <div class="bottom">
      <div class="autor">
        <span>Джонатан Малькольм</span>
        <span>Генеральный директор</span>
      </div>
      <div class="btn">Открыть счёт</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="image">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/cnhXH90.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Использовать отрицательный отступ. Пример:

```css
.container {
  margin-top: 80px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  width: 50%;
  border: 3px solid black;
}

.wrp {
  margin-top: -40px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  width: calc(100% + 40px);
  background: black;
}

.img img {
  margin-top: -40px;
  margin-left: 60%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div container">
  <div class="div wrp">
    <div class="div img"><img src="https://bizseeds.net/uploads/article/image/1117/graphicstock-concentrated-young-businessman-standing-and-reading-newspaper-outdoors_S_E1ztmS3g.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Эм.. А где тут адаптив?